# New Font Not Showing

Tags: fonts, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The new font is not being applied to my xmal label.  I've placed the
font entry in the info.plist and changed the properties as directed.
Build Action = none  Copy to output directory = always copy
The font is not  being implemented,  Am I missing something??

Xmal code snippet:

```
 <Label  x:Name="fontName" Text="Welcome to My Music!" 
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    FontSize = "Large"

    HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <Label.FontFamily>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="ScriptinaPro.ttf" />
           </OnPlatform> 
        </Label.FontFamily>
 </Label>
```

Comment: I think on iOS the value should be font's name and not its file name. Replace "ScriptinaPro.ttf" by "font name" which is without extension

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the font's path in plist is correct:

```
<Label  x:Name="fontName" Text="Welcome to My Music!" 
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    FontSize = "Large"

    HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <Label.FontFamily>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Scriptina Pro" />
           </OnPlatform> 
        </Label.FontFamily>
 </Label>
```

Here is documentation:

[Using custom Fonts in Xamarin.iOS](https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/)

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it. Though it's better to comment below post instead of suggesting an edit.